# Insertar registro nuevo si se cumple una condición

Tags: mariadb

Quisiera saber como se puede insertar un nuevo registro en una tabla al cumplir una condición. En SQLlite se puede por lo que sé, pero en MARIADB no lo puedo lograr. Un ejemplo de lo que quisiera hacer:

```
INSERT INTO rubros (nombre) SELECT 'Articulos varios' WHERE nombre != 'Articulos varios' ;
```

Este código esta testeado y retorna el siguiente error:

> error de sql(1064):Algo esta equivocado en su sintax cerca "WHERE
>   nombre != 'Articulos varios'" en la linea 1

En este caso seria ingresar en la tabla "rubros" el registro con el nombre "Articulos varios" si es que no existiera. Es decir

> INSERT INTO tabla (valor)  SELECT * WHERE (Condicion)
>   En condición si se cumple se inserta el registro.

PD: He probado con esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689582/if-not-exists-mariadb-syntax/45691422#45691422) y no funciono, Tengo la versión de MariaDB 10.3.12.
El codigo que utilize para intentar utilizar "EXISTS" es el siguiente codigo:

```
INSERT INTO rubros (nombre, descripcion) 
SELECT 'Articulos varios', '' 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT nombre FROM rubros WHERE nombre = 'Articulos varios'
)  ;
```

El error que se me presenta es el siguiente:

> error de sql(1064):Algo esta equivocado en su sintax cerca " WHERE
>   EXISTS (SELECT nombre FROM rubros WHERE nombre = 'Articulos varios') 
>   " en la linea 1

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Has probado ese query directamente en MARIADB? Seria bueno que pusieras el código donde estas poniendo el select..

Comment: Obviamente esta probado.. Ahí coloco los errores que me dice, y en una supuesta solución que tampoco funciona!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba usando un FROM en tu consulta, usando la tabla `dual`.

```
INSERT INTO rubros (nombre, descripcion) 
SELECT 'Articulos varios', '' 
FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT nombre FROM rubros WHERE nombre = 'Articulos varios'
)  ;
```

Esto siguiendo la lógica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021231/236345).

Comment: no entiendo porque "dual", pero funciona muchas gracias

Comment: `dual` es una tabla comodín que sirve para estos casos en los que usas datos "fijos" que no vienen de una tabla en particular, útil en estos casos que la sintaxis de la instrucción REQUIERE que incluyas un FROM.

Answer (score -3):

No debería tener un from tu consulta?

```
INSERT INTO rubros (nombre) SELECT 'Artículos varios' From rubros WHERE nombre != 'Artículos varios' ;
```